# How to prevent "Changed successfully" message when overriding save_model method

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to let users view records in the admin but not save anything.  So I'm trying to do something like this:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    """Override save method so no one can save"""
    messages.error(request, "No Changes are permitted from this screen."
        " To edit projects visit the 'Projects' table, and make sure you are"
        " in the group 'Visitor_Program_Managers'.")
```

This works however I get two messages on the next screen:

My message above first
And then a "The ... was changed successfully."

How can I prevent the second message?

Comment: Rather than preventing Django from adding that message, you might be able to instead iterate through messages manually to get rid of the success message. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8265829/2395796) for another approach to making a model read-only in the admin.

Comment: @Greg, what was your solution here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62246926/7300865 only display one message.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can hide certain messages and show others. In your case, you are interested in not displaying the the success message. You can do the following:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    messages.set_level(request, messages.ERROR)
    messages.error(request, 'No changes are permitted ..')
```

Comment: Is there a way to replace both success and error message. I tried but gets two messages for every action. Both custom and default.

Comment: @ShreyaMaria check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62246926/7300865 . Only display one message.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanFareed, Thank you

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who needs to eliminate the automatic Django success message in a more flexible way than proposed by the accepted answer, you can do the following:

```
from django.contrib import messages, admin

class ExampleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def message_user(self, *args):
        pass

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super(ExampleAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        if obj.status == "OK":
            messages.success(request, "OK!")
        elif obj.status == "NO":
            messages.error(request, "REALLY NOT OK!")
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to prevent success message in case of failure message then you must have to set the error level of the messages.

Something like this ->

```
    if already_exist:
        messages.set_level(request, messages.ERROR)
        messages.error(request, 'a and b mapping already exist. Please delete the current entry if you want to override')
    else:
        obj.save()
```

It will avoid coming two messages (Success and Failure) at the same time because we have suppressed success message by changing the error level.

Comment: This is the only answer that finally made it clear to me that changing the message level is what prevents the default success message from displaying.  Well done.

Answer (score 1):

Just override def message_user(...) method, do it as follows:

```
def message_user(self, request, message, level=messages.INFO, extra_tags='',
                 fail_silently=False):
    pass

def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    messages.success(request, 'Write your overrided message here...')
    pass
```